# How to use d3.scaleLinear to find the radius of a map in d3

Tags: d3.js, linear-regression, scale, pie-chart, radius

I have a chart as shown below
[image]

where the radius of the pie chart on the chart is am trying to do it as shown below

```
 <PieChartMarkers
              totalSites={totalSites}
              key={i}
              keymarket={name}
              pieData={pieData}
              x={projection(coordinates)[0]}
              y={projection(coordinates)[1]}
              **radius={this.getMarketRadius(totalCase)}**
              mouseOverHandler={this.showTooltip}
              mouseOutHandler={this.hideTooltip}
            />

  getMarketRadius = (totalCase) => {
    let radius = null;
    // let data=d3.scaleLinear([10,130]).range([0,960]);
    let callback= d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, totalCase])
    .domain([10, 130])
    radius = totalCase / 650 + 10;
    console.log(radius)
    return radius;
  };
```

currently i am getting the radius  radius = totalCase / 650 + 10; which is working fine  but suggestion is to use d3.scaleLinear to get the radius of the on chart when trying to use i am getting the value as 1313316 using the below code snippet

//totalCase is the variable value coming from API

```
let callback= d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, totalCase])
    .domain([10, 130]
```

please help me understand how to get the radius using d3.scaleLinear to draw the pie chart on the map

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use a linear scale to get these radii: we encode the data as the **area** of the circles, not as their radii. That said, you should use `d3.scaleSqrt`. Also, set the `0` range for the `0` domain, because there should be no circle if there are no cases.

So, your function would be something like this:

```
getMarketRadius = totalCase => {
    return d3.scaleLinear().range([0, totalCase]).domain([0, 130])(totalCase);
};
```

A better option is just setting the scale outside the function, and using it directly for setting the `radius`.

```
myScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, totalCase])
    .domain([0, 130]);

radius={this.myScale(totalCase)}
```